# How to rearrange the tags in FIX message?

Tags: c#, .net, quickfix, fix-protocol, quickfixn

I'm sending my fix marketdata request message as:

```
8=FIXT.1.1☺9=168☺35=V☺34=2☺49=XXXXX☺52=20160622-09:50:59.240☺56=XXXX☺262=1976060316☺263=1☺264=1☺265=0☺267=1☺269=0☺146=1☺55=ABC☺48=ABC☺22=8☺167=FXNDF☺762=PERIOD☺20000=1M☺10=165☺
```

In this I followed the order 35=V as follows:

```
55=ABC|48=ABC|22=8|167=FXNDF|762=PERIOD|20000=1M
```

I want to rearrange my message sequence as this:

```
146=1|55=ABC||167=FXNDF|762=PERIOD|48=ABC|20000=1M|22=8
```

I'm using Quickfix DLL.

Comment: Is there a reason for rearranging the tags ?

Comment: as iam sending this message iam getting error as
<incoming> 8=FIXT.1.1☺9=213☺35=W☺49=TMATCH☺56=SPC_MDF_UAT☺34=3☺52=20160622-10:50:03.788☺262=1976060316☺55=USD/INR☺48=USD/INR☺22=8☺167=FXNDF☺762=PERIOD☺20000=1M☺268=2☺269=Q☺270=67.88☺336=1☺625=103☺269=J☺270=0☺271=0☺336=1☺625=103☺290=1☺1187=N☺10=010☺
<event> Message 3 Rejected: Value is incorrect (out of range) for this tag (Field=625)
<outgoing> 8=FIXT.1.1☺9=135☺35=3☺34=3☺49=SPC_MDF_UAT☺52=20160622-10:49:55.376☺56=TMATCH☺45=3☺58=Value is incorrect (out of range) for this tag☺371=625☺372=W☺373=5☺10=045☺

Comment: You don't understand the reject message you get. Check here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29791730/quickfix-j-error-value-out-of-range-for-this-tag

Comment: i saw that link i have 625 field in my fix50sp2..then what is the error?

Comment: `Value is incorrect (out of range) for this tag (Field=625)` - Is that unclear to you?

Comment: @PralayakaveriPallavi **Value is incorrect (out of range)** means: Your counterparty has a **list of values** for the 625 tag (ENUM), but you are sending a value that **is not listed as a valid value**. According to the FIXimate, the valid values are 1 to 7 (check here http://www.fixtradingcommunity.org/FIXimate/FIXimate3.0/en/FIX.5.0SP2/tag625.html ). You are sending 625=103. Probably, your Counterparty does not accept 103 as a valid value. Check the Counterparty's FIX dictionary file.

Comment: i also want  to know how to rearrange my message fields in group?

Comment: @grantbirchmeier you answered the same question in link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24129059/changing-the-order-of-fields-in-a-fix-message  in that you said only repeating groups should follow sequence.i want to know how to follow that  sequnce??

Comment: this is the group which i want to rearrange QuickFix.FIX50.MarketDataRequest.NoRelatedSymGroup symbolGroup = new QuickFix.FIX50.MarketDataRequest.NoRelatedSymGroup();
            symbolGroup.Set(new Symbol("abc"));symbolGroup.Set(new SecurityType("efg"));symbolGroup.Set(new SecuritySubType("PERIOD"));symbolGroup.Set(new SecurityID("abc"));
            symbolGroup.SetField(new StringField(20000, "1M")); symbolGroup.Set(new SecurityIDSource("8"));    QuickFix.FIX50.MarketDataRequest message = new QuickFix.FIX50.MarketDataRequest(mdReqID, subType, marketDepth);   message.AddGroup(symbolGroup);

Comment: Don't you have a FIX technical sheet agreed between you and the counterparty, which mentions the messages and their constituents ? Get that and start reading. You will get loads of these errors while testing. So understanding why this error is happening is very important to fix the errors you might get later

Comment: @PralayakaveriPallavi You are not reading the words that we are typing.  Your problem is not about tag order.

Answer (score 0):

The `out of range` exception you are getting is not a problem with the order of the fields of the FIX4.4 message but a problem with the contents of one particular field tag 625. This tag is *usually* called TradingSessionSubID and is *usually* expecting  STRING content. However your configuration could easily redefine it as something else entirely. Your dictionary definition file will have the precise requirement for your implementation, you'd best look there, the file is often named something like FIX44.xml.

There is rarely any need to rearrange the order of your FIX message fields. You could try changing the order of the fields for your particular message in the dictionary definition file and see if that does it for you.